# eval File.read(file_location) get error in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, rspec, eval

in my rspec testing, i have code like this

```
it 'test'
plan_calcs_from_file = File.read(file_location)
eval(plan_calcs_from_file)
end
```

but when i try to "eval(plan_calcs_from_file)", i get error like this

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid Exception: Mysql2::Error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1 does not exist: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

When i try in development mode this code work fine but in test mode this code get error. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` into the `spec_helper.rb`

You are using Mysql DDE statements (create/drop/truncate table) which will result in an implicit commit.

Because of the implicit commit, all savepoints of the current transaction are deleted.